# ¿obtener datos con linq para un chart C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq

le mando como Datos tipo **List** a un chart pero no se visualiza los datos revise el método que hace la consulta y si retorna los valores pero chart no los carga

```
public void loadDataLinq()
    {
        this.chart1.Palette = ChartColorPalette.EarthTones;
        this.chart1.Titles.Add("Mascotas");

        ConexionBd spQuery = new ConexionBd("Mascotas");
        this.chart1.DataSource = spQuery.mLinq();
        this.chart1.DataBind();

    }

        public List<object> mLinq()
    {
        var Mascotas = from tMAscota in Context.Mascotas
                         select new
                         {
                             Mascota = tMAscota.Mascota1,
                             CantidaD = tMAscota.Cantidad,
                         };
        return Mascotas.AsEnumerable<object>().ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Has depurado para ver que la consulta linq efectivamente devuelve filas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Necesitas usar una clase intermedia para obtener los datos lo cual seria:

```
public class Mascotas
    {
        public string Mascota { get; set; }
        public int Cantidad { get; set; }
    }
```

Ahora debes hacer uso de la clase intermedia en tu consulta Linq ya que chart no puede usar tipos anonimos como datos:

```
public List<Mascotas> mLinq()
    {
        var _Mascotas = from tMAscota in Context.Mascotas
                         select new Mascotas()
                         {
                             Mascota = tMAscota.Mascota1,
                             Cantidad = tMAscota.Cantidad,
                         };
        return _Mascotas.ToList();
    }
```

y para finalizar debes especificar los datos que usara el grafico:

```
public void loadDataLinq()
    {
        this.chart1.Palette = ChartColorPalette.EarthTones;
        this.chart1.Titles.Add("Mascotas");

        ConexionBd spQuery = new ConexionBd("Mascotas");
        var datosMascota = spQuery.mLinq(); //Lista de datos
        this.chart1.DataBindTable(datosMascota, "Mascota"); //Usamos Mascota como eje X
        chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line; //Agregamos la serie y el tipo de grafica a usar en el grafico, debe asignar automaticamente Cantidad como eje Y
        this.chart1.DataBind();
    }
```

Dando como resultado: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos

Comment: entonces es normal que tenga que crear clases cada conjunto de datos diferentes ala las clases que generera el modelo ?

Comment: @LuisAlbertoAcosta si usas los metodos de binding del chart, solo es posible mediante clases intermedias ya que no aceptan tipos genericos como valores, ahora que si requieres usar tipos genericos habria que hacer los binding sobre los puntos de la serie

Comment: asi chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Mascota";
            chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueType = ChartValueType.String;
            chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Cantidad";
            chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;

Comment: intente con un proceso almacenado traer los datos asi: return Context.sp_getMascotas().ToList(); pero me da error de sintaxis "no se puede convertir result a clase mascota" sabes como solucionarlo?

Comment: `var resultado = Context.Database.SqlQuery<Mascotas>("Nombre_SP_Aqui");` los nombres de las columnas retornadas por el sp deben de coincidir con los nombres de las propiedades de la clase Mascota y empatar sus tipos de datos

Comment: ya me trae los datos pero no lo muestra en un chart tipo Pie ,necesita configurarlo algo para que funcione tipo pie?

Comment: No hay que hacer ninguna configuracion diferente, asegurate de que la serie asignada al grafico tenga datos asignados que graficar, Saludos

Comment: pos estuve probando creo que agregas nuevos datos y no remplazan los anteriores en el chart tipo Bar tengo "Series1, Cantidad" y en la tipo pie "cantiadad" pero deberia aparecer los tipo de mascota y lo tengo igual que tu respuesta pero cambie tipo a Pie

Answer (score 3):

las demas respuesta son correctas solo pongo una alternativa sin tener que crear otra clase

```
public void loadChart()
    {
        List<object> Data = new ConexionBd().getMascotas();
        chart1.DataSource = Data;
        chart1.Titles.Add("Animales");
        chart1.Palette = ChartColorPalette.EarthTones;
        chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Mascota";
        chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueType = ChartValueType.String;
        chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Cantidad";
        chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
    }
```

Comment: Correcto si quieres hacer uso de tipos genericos sin tener que realizar clases intermedias, la unica desventaja es que se puede volver mas complejo conforme mas series agregas que hacer una clase intermedia y dejar que el control chart realice la inferencia

Answer (score 1):

El problema probablemente viene derivado de devolver una lista de objetos para tratar de pasar un tipo anónimo en tu método `mLinq`. Lo que debes hacer es crear una clase y usarla para ese paso de datos:

```
public class GraficaMascotas
{
     public string Mascota {get;set;}
     public int CantidaD {get;set;}
}

public List<GraficaMascotas> mLinq()
{
    var Mascotas = from tMAscota in Context.Mascotas
                     select new GraficaMascota()
                     {
                         Mascota = tMAscota.Mascota1,
                         CantidaD = tMAscota.Cantidad,
                     };
    return Mascotas.ToList();
}
```